# Mega API Client: CancellationToken em DownloadFileAsync

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, nuget

Eu comecei usar uma API da nuvem de arquivos MEGA em que posso fazer upload e download dos arquivos da nuvem. [Pacote Nuget aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MegaApiClient/), estou indo bem:

```
using CG.Web.MegaApiClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsMegaDownload
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private double bytesTotal;
        private long bytesT;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            
            var client = new MegaApiClient();
            client.Login("Meu Email", "Senha");

            //INode principal
            IEnumerable<INode> home = client.GetNodes();
            List<INode> homeContent = home.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.Directory).ToList();
            INode home_jogos = homeContent.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Jogos");
            
            //Node da home\\pasta
            IEnumerable<INode> jogos = client.GetNodes(home_jogos);
            List<INode> allfiles = jogos.Where(n => n.Type == NodeType.File).ToList();
            INode myFile = allfiles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "sparkle_setup.exe");

            bytesTotal = double.Parse(myFile.Size.ToString()) / 1024 / 1024;
            bytesT = myFile.Size;

            var progress = new Progress<double>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<double>(progressChanged);

            Thread progressCompleted = new Thread(new ThreadStart(progressComplete));
            progressCompleted.Start();

            client.DownloadFileAsync(myFile, "sparkle_setup.exe", progress);
            
        }

        private void progressComplete()
        {
            bool completed = false;
            while (!completed)
            {
                if (File.Exists("sparkle_setup.exe"))
                {
                    if(new FileInfo("sparkle_setup.exe").Length == bytesT)
                    {
                        completed = true;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }

        private void progressChanged(object sender, double e)
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(new FileInfo("sparkle_setup.exe").Length.ToString()) / 1024 / 1024;
            

            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e);
            label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "% | " + bytesIn.ToString("F2") + "/" + bytesTotal.ToString("F2") + " MB";
        }
    }
}
```

Em JIT:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro começa com o login para entrar, depois cria INodes que são o caminho das pastas da nuvem até chegar aquilo que precisa. Como o MegaApiClient, a classe não é semelhante a da WebClient sobre os eventos decidi fazer manualmente. [Método DownloadFileAsync](https://gpailler.github.io/MegaApiClient/api/CG.Web.MegaApiClient.MegaApiClient.html#CG_Web_MegaApiClient_MegaApiClient_DownloadFileAsync_CG_Web_MegaApiClient_INode_System_String_System_IProgress_System_Double__System_Nullable_System_Threading_CancellationToken__).

```
public Task DownloadFileAsync(INode node, string outputFile, IProgress<double> progress = null, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken? ))
```

Esse é a estrutura do método, coloquei o INode do arquivo que eu tinha (nem me lembrava dele), o caminho de saída e um item Progress que faz o progressChanged. Apenas não entendi esse `CancellationToken? cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken? )`. Ele tem algo haver em relação se o progresso concluiu ou não?
Não fiz nada em relação desse parâmetro em vez disso criei um thread de DownloadCompleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um `CancelationToken` é um objeto usado para notificar uma *thread* que o código quem iniciou o processo deseja cancelar.

Como uma *thread* é um processo assíncrono, o código que inicio "perde" o controle sobre ele, e fica aguardando que seja notificado que o processo da *thread* terminou, o que chamamos de *callback*.

Agora imagina que por alguma razão se deseja cancelar isso, ou porque não precisa mais, porque está demorarando muito (*timeout*) ou outra razão qualquer, isso não seria possível pois o processo é assíncrono, então o `CancelationToken` é um "elo de ligação" por assim dizer com o processo que iniciou a *thread* e ela, e pode usar isso para notificar que deseja que seja cancelado o processo.

Nesse ponto, a *thread* deve saber tratar isso. No seu exemplo foi usado `DownloadFileAsync`, então provavelmente o download será cancelado.

Para fazer isso, crie um objeto, não passe o "default", assim:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
```

E para cancelar, use o método `Cancel()`:  `source.Cancel();`

Pode ler mais sobre aqui: [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-5.0)